# Is the orthogonal complement a complementable submodule?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

Let $H$ be a Hilbert $C^*$-module over some $C^*$-algebra $A$, and consider a closed submodule $M\subseteq H$. Then it is well-known that $M$ is not necessarily orthogonally complementable in $H$. That is, we do not necessarily have (as one does when $A=\mathbb{C}$) the relation

$$H\cong M\oplus M^{\perp}.$$

As an example of this phenomenon, one can let $A = C(\mathbb{R})$, the continuous functions $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, let $H = A$ be the Hilbert module with the $A$-valued inner product given by $(a,b) = a^*b$, and let $M$ be the closed submodule of functions in $A$ that vanish at $0$.

However, I noticed in this case that we still have that $M^{\perp\perp}\oplus M^{\perp} = H\oplus\{0\}\cong H$.

**Question:** Is it always true that for a closed submodule $M$ of $H$, we have $H = M^\perp\oplus M^{\perp\perp}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. In fact, let $A = C[0, 1]$ and $M = \{f \in A \mid \mathrm{supp}\, f \subset [0, 1/2]\}$. Then $M^{\perp} = \{g \mid \mathrm{supp}\, g \subset [1/2, 1]\}$, $M = M^{\perp\perp}$ and $H \ne M^{\perp\perp}\oplus M^{\perp}$.

Comment: I guess it's obvious, but not to me. What would $H$ be?

Comment: @MartinArgerami $H=A$ like in OP's example.

Comment: I totally missed that. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinArgerami What I'm trying to say is that for a submodule of functions $f$ with $\mathrm{supp} f \subset U$ the orthogonal submodule consists of functions $f$ with $\mathrm{supp} f \subset [0, 1] \setminus U$. In OP's example it is a submodule of continuous functions with support in $\{0\}$ so the trivial submodule. But for "most" other choices of $U$ it is not and $A = H \ne M^{\perp} \oplus M^{\perp\perp}$.

Comment: Yes, that's great. Maybe you should emphasize in your answer how general your example is.